# select option and change propriety object svg

Tags: javascript, html

I want choose a option in a combo box html, and alter propriety object SVG.

this is the code who I have problems:

my object :

```
<svg  width="50" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">    
                <rect id="cercle1" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"  stroke-width="1" stroke="#0E0E0E" style="fill:red; stroke:black; stroke-width:2"; />
            </svg> 

<select onchange="select()" id="selectobject">
            <option value="rect" >Rectangle rouge</option>
            <option value="circle">Circle vert</option>
            <option value="rectb">Resctangle Blue</option>
    </select>
    <label> chousir colour </label>
    <select onchange="select()" id="selectcolour">
            <option value="rouge" >Rouge</option>
            <option value="vert">Vert</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="noir">Noir</option>
    </select>
        <button onclick="setColor();">Generate</button>
```

and the javascript

function select(){

```
                var selected = document.getElementById("selectobject").value;

                var selectedcolour = document.getElementById("selectcolour").value;

                if (selected == "rect" && selectedcolour == "rouge" ){
                    alert("rectangle rouge");

                        //function setColor(){
                            document.getElementById("cercle1").style.fill = blue;
                        //}

                    }
```

}

and when select option, I can't change for example color.

thanks for your help.

Comment: style.background = blue;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add quotes to "blue", like this:

document.getElementById("cercle1").style.fill = "blue";

This will work:

```
function select(){

                var selected = document.getElementById("selectobject").value;

                var selectedcolour = document.getElementById("selectcolour").value;

                if (selected == "rect" && selectedcolour == "rouge" ){
                    alert("rectangle rouge");


                        setColor("blue");

                    }
}

function setColor(color){
                            document.getElementById("cercle1").style.fill = color;
                        }
```

Comment: thanks, and now I can pass a color with parameter. example: setcolor("blue"), and in function and parameter color but not work

Comment: thanks, yes I do this, but is a button onclick to generate. onclick="setColor(color);">

Comment: You also can: setColor(selectedcolour); but then you must to redefine option values in english in selectcolour select.